# In Romans 8:1, what does "in Christ" mean?

Tags: soteriology, hell, righteousness

What "are in christ" means in romans.8:1?

How do I get to be in Christ so that I would have no condemnation?

Comment: As I said on [your other Romans 8:1 question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19850/could-you-add-in-romans-81-made-righteous-either-just-before-in-christ-or-a), I think you need to specify a doctrinal perspective in order for a question like this to be answerable. You might also like to check through some of our past questions in [soteriology](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soteriology) to make sure your specific question, whatever it turns out to be, hasn't been answered already.

Comment: Can just anyone first point out in his answer that what doctrinal perspective they represent? I mean that if someone takes from the perspective of catholic doctrine on "in Christ" and another takes perspective of Protestant doctrine on "in Christ"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How do I get to be in Christ so that I would have no condemnation?" According to Romans 6:11, "Likewise you also reckon yourselves to be dead indeed to sin, but alive to God in Christ Jesus our Lord." It is obtained practically through reckoning it so by faith, as this verse says.

We accept Jesus by faith as the one who saves us from our sins (Rom. 5:1). To be practically saved from its effects in our lives, we go the next step, as outlined in Romans 6. We see that as Jesus was buried and rose again, we too (our old nature) had been buried and our (new) nature is risen with Him, separate from the old nature buried below (see Rom. 6:1-10).

This is a reckoning faith in that the Bible says this process is true and ready to be put into action, and when we reckon it is so and practice it, then we enjoy its benefits.

To take this practically, when temptation arises, we surrender our mind and body to serve Christ instead of the motions of the flesh, and start serving Him (Rom. 6:11-14). With this reckoning, to use Paul's word, all the passages of "in Christ" become available to us, including the ones you seek, righteousness in Christ and no condemnation to those in Christ, Rom. 8:1.

But if we continue in the flesh and not die to it, then we will know self-condemnation or self-righteousness. Paul counted everything he formerly trusted in as loss so that he may have the righteousness of Christ (Phil. 3:8-9). He didn't think it enough to believe in Jesus for salvation once long ago. To get the righteousness that receives a reward, all his trust needed to be in Christ. He "died to sin" in that he ceased trusting in old forms of righteousness.

He had obtained positional righteousness without the law by faith alone. Now through reckoning himself dead to sin alive to God he was reaching out to practical righteousness that will be rewarded at the judgment seat. It is this latter point I am addressing in this answer, living in practical righteousness.

Comment: How do you define reckoning faith?

Comment: @laovultai I take it from the Greek of "reckon," which means in part to put to the account of. So God has said that we are dead to sin; we are to reckon that to our bank account and live off of it by faith.

Comment: So in short, do you mean that by this reckoning faith you get to be in Christ? How does this kind of faith differs from the faith that is defined in romans.10:17 and eph.2:8?

Comment: @laovultai They are entirely different contexts. In Rom 6, Paul makes a statement of fact that we Christians are dead to sin and alive to God. He's telling us to reckon it so, and serve God rather than the flesh. In Rom 10:17 and Eph 2:8, the context is entirely different, which is entering the family of God by faith through the gospel. If 'reckoning faith' confuses you, then just take it as Paul wrote it: 'reckon.'

Comment: @laovultai I changed the answer. Hope it clarifies things.

Comment: I would like to apologise. Sorry.

Comment: @laovultai Your questions were good!

Comment: I would like to ask that what you think about following sentence: I understand now that to be "in Christ" means that you walk in life dying to sin and that is reckoning faith. So is "to be in Christ" same as reckoning faith?

Comment: To reckon yourself dead to sin is a step of faith, of believing God for this truth. So reckoning faith is accepting by faith something God has already done for you. "In Christ" is not reckoning faith, but our position before God. To fully enjoy the blessings of being in Christ, you accept them as God's blessing for yourself and live as though they were true (reckoning them as true by faith).

Comment: @Stevee So this romans.8:1 situation is achieved by reckoning myself dead to sin?

Comment: @Steve.. Do you agree that to reckon myself dead to sin(rom.6:11) means also that you confess to be in christ and dead to sin? So to reckon refers to the facts and to confessing them.

Comment: @laovultai Yes, that is how I understand it.

Comment: $Steve: But you said that you come to be in christ By reckoning myself to dead to sin; By reckoning faith. Isn't it. So you cannot reckon yourself to sin just By confessing you are in Christ and that you are dead to sin, but rather otherwise; you come to be in Christ By reckoning yourself dead to sin; isn't it? if you get to be in Christ By this reckoning faith; reckoning yourself dead to sin then you are basically saved By reckoning yourself dead to sin and when you are not reckoning yourself dead to sin you're not in Christ anymore or what?

Comment: @laovultai I did not discuss how we come to be in Christ. When you accept Christ and His offer of salvation, then you are placed in Christ. The problem is that people continue to live in the flesh, not recognizing the blessings they have in Christ until later, which are activated by faith, not fleshly efforts.

Comment: Just one more question; you said "With this reckoning, to use Paul's word, all the passages of "in Christ" become available to us, including the ones you seek, righteousness in Christ and no condemnation to those in Christ, Rom. 8:1" Do you mean that without reckoning myself dead to sin, romans.8:1 cannot happen to me? In other words if I'm not reckoning myself dead to sin, I cannot be in Christ and I cannot get rid of 'condemnation', isn't it?

Comment: @Stevee...: Do you agree that 'reckon' in rom.6:11 can be translated as 'see' as in here[http://www.ihopkc.org/resources/asset/2015_12_06_1030_MB_FCF/auto/true/ -> Notes(page 2 at the bottom)].

Comment: @alvoutila We are not supposed to use comments to have a conversation. It is against site rules. If you'd like to continue, please open a chat.