# Could you add in romans.8:1 "made righteous" either just before "in Christ" or after "in Christ"?

Tags: soteriology, righteousness

Could you add in romans.8:1 "made righteous" either just before "in Christ" or after "in Christ" and if it is doctrinally heresy, then why?
I mean that how do you get to be "in Christ" if you are not first be made righteous? Or is "in Christ" same as "to make righteous( justified, saved)"?

Comment: The question of whether something is "doctrinally heresy" is difficult to answer without a grounding doctrinal tradition, especially since the something is about righteousness, justification and salvation - classic contentious topics. Can you narrow down the doctrinal perspective you are interested in?

Comment: @JamesT Can you answer the last question, because if answer to this is yes then my other questions are unnecessary? Or is this difficult to answer, because of contentiousness?

Comment: Do you mean answer your question http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19849/what-in-christ-means-in-romans-81, or the question in the last sentence above? In any case I think the interpretation depends on how one understands justification, etc.

Comment: I mean last question of above question

Comment: See my answer to this (reworded) question in http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19849/what-in-christ-means-in-romans-81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could add "made righteous" to "in Christ" but, first of all, the text doesn't say that, and secondly, that would be redundant since the term "in Christ" is the most complete description of salvation, it encompasses the full spectrum of all that God has in store for His saints Colossians 2:9 - 10  "For in him [in Christ] dwelleth all the fulness of the Godhead bodily. and ye are complete in him, which is the head of all principality and power"  So if you want to add "made righteous" or justified, you should also add sanctified, redeemed, reconciled, saved, glorified... and we could keep going on or we could just simply say, in Christ and there's no need to say anything else.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). This is actually a decent answer to a poorly phrased question.